# Lighting Without gl_LightSource[0]

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, glsl, lwjgl

What is the equivalent of `gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz` when writing in `GLSL`? In other words, how would I take a `vec3` (or `vec4`) in `GLSL` and apply the same transformations to it that OpenGL applies to `gl_LightSource[0].position`? Is there a `mat4` I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you like. That's the nice thing about shaders. Define yourself a set of uniforms that describe a light. Its position may in any space you desire, you just have to somehow apply the right transformations.

Shaders are all about free choice, you can do whatever suits you best. Fixed function OpenGL does illumination calculations in eye/view space, i.e. after the modelview transform. To do this, it transforms the light position with the modelview, right when you call `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT…, GL_POSITION, …)`. Then when drawing geometry, after the modelview transform has been applied as well, the illumination calculation is performed in view space.

Comment: When I try to do this in my fragment shader, I get strange lighting errors. The code is basically replacing `gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz` with `(gl_ModelViewMatrix*lightPos).xyz`, where lightPos is the light position as a vec4. But the lighting ends up looking different from when I was using `gl_LightSource[0]`.

Comment: @Abaab: gl_ListSource[0].position is the untransformed light position as set with `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT…, GL_POSITION, …)` … it acts exactly like a generic uniform and no special treatment is applied. You have to apply the transform in the shader code, no matter if you use a generic uniform or a built-in state variable. Shaders **are not** fixed function, so any fixed function processing must be recreated (hence convenience functions like `ftransform`). Also transforming the light position with the modelview matrix for the object may not be the right thing.

Comment: @Abaab: On a general note, when using shaders you should not use the FFP built-in uniforms at all. There's no benefit in doing this. Always use generic uniforms and define those transforms that suit your problem best. It's madness to constrain yourself into FFP semantics when using shaders.

Comment: Wait... I thought `gl_LightSource[0].position` was affected by `glTranslatef()` and `glRotatef()`. Am I missing something? Also, if transforming the light position with the modelview matrix is not the right thing to do, what is?

Comment: @Abaab: The light position in **fixed function** is affected by the modelview matrix. But when you're using shaders it is **your** responsibility to do *everything* that's done by fixed function otherwise. This includes transforming the light position. The matrix you use to multiply is completely up to you. However the usual approach is to transform the light position on the client side into view coordinates and pass the light position in view coordinates into the shader by uniform. Or you pass the matrix by which to transform the light position by in a separate uniform.

Comment: @Abaab: BTW, you should not use `gl_LightSource[…]`. It's deprecated. You can't use it with OpenGL-3 core and later. However a set of custom uniforms will work with OpenGL-2.x just like it will with OpenGL-3 core. Doing it that way is the future proof method. In the same way you shouldn't use gl_ModelviewMatrix

Comment: Okay, I'll mess around with the lighting a little more. I really don't like working with `gl_LightSource[...]` and had been wondering for a while if this was actually what graphics engines used. Thanks!

Comment: @Abaab: I recommend the tutorial at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut – regarding illumination calculations the tutorials at http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/ are good, too.